# Django connecting to existing postgressql database

Tags: django, amazon-rds

I have a legacy web2py application which connects as an admin application to an RDS Postgresql instance in the backend. This databse serves as backend for other applications

I am working on a django project to replace this web2py app.

What is the best strategy for replacing the web2py app with a django one? Is it possible to keep the current live db that serves the other applications?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to keep the legacy DB!

In your case you need to create your models from the existing DB. To do that you can use `manage.py inspectdb`

You can take a look here how to do it:

[Tutorial](https://django-book.readthedocs.io/en/latest/chapter18.html)

[Oficial documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/legacy-databases/)

Comment: do I need to create all models? I have tried selecting just a single table in the inspectdb method, but trying to access the admin page yielded an error

Comment: I'm not sure, but if your table has relations you should create the models for those relationships. The error you're getting in the admin should help you to know what's happening